# SQL Find MAX and truncate

Tags: sql, max

I have a datetime field that I'd like to find the max value on and then truncate it so that I only have 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

My statement is

```
select TO_CHAR(MAX(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as UPDATE_DATE from        
BUS.ZIP_ACTIVITY
where zip = '01001' order by AUDIT_TIMESTAMP
```

This fails. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Remove the ORDER BY, not needed since there's only one row returned. (Also, it's wrong.)

Comment: I'm always surprised when I see a question that says that it fails, but doesn't post the error message or any explanation about what fails. In this case though, it's the `order by`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `ORDER BY`.  It has a column that is not recognized, because you have an aggregation query.  The query only returns one row, so the `ORDER BY` isn't necessary at all.  So:

```
select TO_CHAR(MAX(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as UPDATE_DATE
from BUS.ZIP_ACTIVITY
where zip = '01001' ;
```

If you wanted this for all zips:

```
select zip, TO_CHAR(MAX(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as UPDATE_DATE
from BUS.ZIP_ACTIVITY
group by zip;
```

Note:  This assumes that your database supports the `to_char()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(AUDIT_TIMESTAMP), "%Y-%m-%d") as UPDATE_DATE
FROM BUS.ZIP_ACTIVITY
WHERE zip = '01001'
```

Comment: Any reason to change `TO_CHAR` to `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: Only if you use MySQL instead of Oracle. I was thinking that he was using MySQL.